# RestyGWT mapping

Tags: rest, gwt, resty-gwt

Im trying to play with RestyGWT. So I try to create simple API and deploy it. 
My API is available at http://127.0.0.1:8888/api/hellos.

But client tries to connect to http://127.0.0.1:8888/**TestApp**/api/hellos

Can you please advice what I do wrong (Maybe some suggestions).

Some screenshots:

1. My client class.
   [image: client class]
2. My server class.
   [image: My server class]
3. That's how I call remote method.
   [[image: That's how I call remote method[3]]
4. My web.xml and *.gwt.xml.
   [image: My web.xml and *.gwt.xml]
5. Error, wrong address (I don't know why client add **TestApp**).
   [image: I don't know why client add TestApp]
6. But API is available (at another path).
   [image: But API is available]

Comment: Did you try using `Defaults.setServiceRoot(String)` to set your service root, as suggested in [the guide](https://resty-gwt.github.io/documentation/restygwt-user-guide.html)?

Comment: Its working! Thank you Boris. Cпасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Boris Brudnoy aswer:

`Defaults.setServiceRoot(String);`

[Doc](https://resty-gwt.github.io/documentation/restygwt-user-guide.html)